# Odoo12 tree record datetime, export values

Tags: odoo-12

Odoo12 tree record shows different datetime to when the record is exported.
How do i solve this problem

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking a question

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code think, because the datetime is correctly stored in the database but wrong dates are displayed in the system and when the data is exported then i get the correct datetime values from the database. It could be with my server time configuration